# running octave/matlab code in interface mode

Tags: python, matlab, octave

If we run a program with `-i` flag in Python, the program gets executed and we enter interactive mode after executing the script. ( Which can be further used for debugging).

Example : `python -i exampleProgram.py`.

Is there a similar method to do the same in Octave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is

```
--persist    Go interactive after --eval or reading from FILE.
```

see `octave --help` for a full list

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.1/Command-Line-Options.html) is a list of the command line arguments for Octave. You will see that it does support

> --interactive
>
> -i
>
> Force interactive behavior. This can be useful for running Octave via a
>   remote shell command or inside an Emacs shell buffer. For
>   another way to run Octave within Emacs, see Emacs Octave Support.